# Dynamic route in NextJS for username /@[username]

Tags: reactjs, next.js

for my blog app in NextJS I'm trying to create a route for usernames. If a user navigates to `/@${username}` I want to display the page in `/pages/[username]/index.tsx`. That works but if I randomly navigate to `/abc` it displays that page (with an error, obviously) and not the default 404 page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to implement the desired behavior is with `getServerSideProps`:

```
import type { GetServerSideProps } from "next";

type UserPageProps = {
  username: string;
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<UserPageProps> = async ({
  params,
}) => {
  if (params && params.username) {
    const username = Array.isArray(params.username)
      ? params.username[0]
      : params.username;
    if (username.at(0) === "@") {
      return { props: { username: username.substring(1) } };
    }
  }
  return { notFound: true };
};

export default function UserPage({ username }: UserPageProps) {
  return <>Hello, {username}</>;
}
```

But keep in mind that `getServerSideProps` would disable static site generation (SSG).

A better option would be to pre-render all users' pages at build time using `getStaticPaths`:

```
import type { GetStaticPaths, GetStaticProps } from "next";

type UserPageProps = {
  username: string;
};

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths<UserPageProps> = async () => {
  // obtain all usernames from db/CMS/etc.
  const usernames = ["foo", "bar"];
  return {
    paths: usernames.map((username) => ({
      params: { username: `@${username}` },
    })),
    fallback: false,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<UserPageProps> = async ({
  params,
}) => {
  if (params && params.username) {
    const username = Array.isArray(params.username)
      ? params.username[0]
      : params.username;
    if (username.at(0) === "@") {
      return { props: { username: username.substring(1) } };
    }
  }

  return { notFound: true };
};

export default function UserPage({ username }: UserPageProps) {
  return <>Hello, {username}</>;
}
```

Another option would be to use `router` on the client and check the `router.query.username` after hydration.

Comment: in what world would be a better approach to query 200 million + records in the database into a giant list array just to check if the route begins with "@"?

Comment: In a world where a blog app has just hundreds or thousands of authors and the goal is to statically render all blog posts at build time.

Comment: So for every user who tries to load the page, or refresh the page, you could pressure the database to execute millions of queries per just 1 user request. how is this good again?

Comment: Because in the above example that query runs only once at build time and all pages get statically rendered.

Comment: And what if new users register on the platform after build time, that means they wont get added to the list due to only existing after build time

Comment: `fallback` and `revalidate` to the rescue - https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-static-paths

Answer (score 2):

I'm blind-flying on this right now as I don't have Next.js and/or Node installed on my current machine, but is it an idea to create a redirect from `/@${username}` to `/${username}`?

If that could work for you, try adding the following to your `next.config.js`:

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  // Other configuration options
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/@:username',
        destination: '/user/:username',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

With this configuration, when a user navigates to `/@[username]`, it will redirect to `/user/[username]`, which will be handled by the dynamic route file at `pages/user/[username].tsx`.

Comment: I want to keep the @ in the url, but I reckon I can modify the destination as `/user/[@username]` to make it work

Comment: This redirect doesn't work as expected. `/@abc` redirects to `/user/c`

Comment: I just provided a better solution after trying things locally. My apologies for the confusion. Can you please **downvote** my **first** answer, and check if my second answer is better? Also, I found out that the issue of the `/user/[last character]` was caused by the asterisks `*` in `next.config.js`.

Answer (score 1):

After getting my Node.js installation up and running and initializing a new Next.js project, I found out that you can use [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/rewrites) instead of redirects.

> Rewrites act as a URL proxy and mask the destination path, making it appear the user hasn't changed their location on the site. In contrast, [redirects](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/redirects) will reroute to a new page and show the URL changes.

---

```js
/* next.config.js */

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/@:username',
        destination: '/user/:username',
      },
    ];
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig
```

```js
/* pages/user/[username].tsx */

import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const UsernamePage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { username } = router.query;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>User Profile: {username}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UsernamePage;
```